# react js: mapping through accordion

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to craete a accordation i want a date as accodation title only ones and  every record in that time to occure inside the accodation content

```
      <div className="accordion">
        {predefined.map(({ date ,time }) => (
          <div className="accordion-item">
            <div
              className="accordion-title"
              onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}
            >
              <div>{date}</div> <div>11:45</div> <div>painscale</div>
              <div>4</div>
              <div>{isActive ? "-" : "+"}</div>
            </div>
            {isActive && <div className="accordion-content">{time}</div>} /// every time in a day a record is created must apperar here
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

}

Comment: What part of your code is not working as intended?

Comment: i am trying to set this  accordion such that if date is 2010-10-05 there are 3 record here(8,9,10) i want that 3 to show under the accodation title

Comment: here only 2 accordations must show because only 2 dates data are only added but since there 10 record 10 accordations is shown now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should map you data first, like this :

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, date: "2021-10-04", time: "18:00" },
  { id: 1, date: "2021-10-04", time: "19:00" },
  { id: 1, date: "2021-10-05", time: "20:00" },
  { id: 1, date: "2021-10-05", time: "21:00" }
];
let mapped = data.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.date] = [...(r[a.date] || []), a];
  return r;
}, {});
```

then you loop through the values of the reduced object like this :

```
{Object.values(mapped).map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h1>
            Section {item[0].date}
          </h1>
          <div>
            {item.map((e) => {
              return <p key={e.time}>{e.time}</p>;
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
))}
```

You should apply this to your example.

Comment: thanku this worked i have one more problem when evere i click on any accordation every accordation opens can u help me with that i want only one accordation to open at a time

Comment: you should accept the answer if it solves your problem, for the other issue you should provide more details ( code ) !